# Azure DevOps User CAL License for TFS 2013

Tags: azure-devops, tfs

As per the below document dated 03-Dec-2020, if we buy monthly access to Azure Devops, we can have user CAL to use Azure DevOps Server (TFS 2015 to Azure DevOps 2020) .  When we check for [TFS 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/buy-access-tfs-test-hub?view=azure-devops-2020&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops), it says "The requested page is not available for Team Foundation Server 2013. You have been redirected to the newest product version this page is available for."

We would like to know as per [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/buy-basic-access-add-users?view=azure-devops-2020) -- -- if we have monthly access to Azure Devops, then can we have access to both Azure DevOps Services and Azure DevOps Server User CAL (TFS 2013)  ?

Answer (score 0):

No, only Azure DevOps Server 2019 supports that behavior. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/devops/server/

[image]